# Reduce verbosity of method call with array of a lengthy generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there anyway to shorten the call to this method?  It seems to long, is the second parameter needed the strongly typed and does the  needed on the FindPercent if the List is known?

```
Model.FindPercent<IStatisticDisplay>(t => t.FaceoffsWon, 
    new Func<IStatisticDisplay, double?>[] { q => q.FaceoffsWon, q => q.FaceoffsLost }, "-")
```

Method

```
public static string FindPercent<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, double?> numerator, 
    Func<T, double?>[] totals, string defValue)
{
    return Helper.FindPercent(list, numerator, totals, defValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `params` and drop the types !

```cs
public static string FindPercent<T>(this List<T> list, string defValue, Func<T, double?> numerator, params Func<T, double?>[] totals)
{
   return Helper.FindPercent(list, numerator, totals, defValue);
}

Model.FindPercent("-", t => t.FaceoffsWon, q => q.FaceoffsWon, q => q.FaceoffsLost );
```